# How to check view in memory stack? Application crash in Shopify ProxyView in ios

Tags: ios, swift, crash, shopify-app

App crash while scroll. and receive stack in unreadable memory.

```
private class ProxyView: UIView {

    weak var headerView: UIView?
    weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        if let scrollView = self.scrollView,
            let headerView = self.headerView {

            /* ---------------------------------
             ** Test if the point is contained
             ** by the scroll view first.
             */
            let scrollViewPoint = scrollView.convert(point, from: self)
            if scrollView.point(inside: scrollViewPoint, with: event) {

                /* -----------------------------------
                 ** Ensure that the point doesn't fall
                 ** into scroll view's inset space at
                 ** the top.
                 */
                if scrollViewPoint.y > 0.0 {
                    return scrollView.hitTest(scrollViewPoint, with: event)
                }
            }

            /* ------------------------------------
             ** Then test if the point is contained
             ** by the header view.
             */
            let headerPoint = headerView.convert(point, from: self)
            if headerView.point(inside: headerPoint, with: event) {
                return headerView.hitTest(headerPoint, with: event)
            }

        } else {
            print("ParallaxViewController must have a non-nill headerView and scrollView assigned to it.")
        }

        return self.superview?.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
```

> `error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x16eed7d90.`

How to stop this error?

Comment: issue on Shopify Mobile by sdk:-  https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/issues/938